# Error: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException

Tags: java

Error in following code is: `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: adding container's parent to itself.`

This is the code:

```
public class humev extends JFrame implements ActionListener{

    //Dichiarazione variabili e costanti

    private static final int larghezza = 1300;
    private static final int altezza = 1000;
    private static final String nome = "Human Evolution";

    private JLabel lab;
    private JButton gioca;
    private JPanel pang;

        public humev(){

            try{
                pang = new JPanel();
                gioca = new JButton("Gioca!");
                gioca.addActionListener(this);
                lab = new JLabel();

                gioca.add(gioca);
                lab.add(lab);
                pang.setLayout(null);
                }
            catch(Exception e1){
                System.err.println(e1);
                System.err.println("Impossibile caricare il frame di gioco!");
                }
        }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        //Finestra
        try{
            humev h = new humev();

            JFrame finestra = new JFrame(nome);

            Dimension dim_finestra = new Dimension(larghezza, altezza);

            finestra.setPreferredSize(dim_finestra);
            finestra.setMaximumSize(dim_finestra);
            finestra.setResizable(false);
            finestra.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
            finestra.pack();
            finestra.setVisible(true);

        }
        catch(Exception e2){
            System.err.println(e2);
            System.err.println("Impossibile caricare la finestra. Frame non caricato");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        if(e.getSource() == gioca){
            lab.setText("Gioco avviato con successo!");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: and also `gioca.add(gioca)`

Comment: and what should I do exactly? Sorry, I'm a beginner in java :)

Comment: where do you want to add lab and gioca component ? you can't add component to itself .and you have extend your class with jframe but you are creating a new frame inside main method. you have created components but you haven't add them to jframe .there are lot mistakes

Comment: I understood, thanks. But how do I add the objects within the frame?

Comment: @FrankSoll since you have extends your class with jframe .create new object of your class and call set visible method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try to run this example.there is bunch of problems in your code.

you are adding component to itself

```
gioca.add(gioca); // don't do this
```

use layouts .don't use null

```
pang.setLayout(null); // don't do this .use layouts .and even if you use null then
//use bounds to absolutely position .if you use null layout and if you add using `.add()` 
//then you will not see those components .
```

complete code

```
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.*;

public class humev extends JFrame implements ActionListener {

    private static final int larghezza = 1300;
    private static final int altezza = 1000;
    private static final String nome = "Human Evolution";

    private final JLabel lab;
    private final JButton gioca;
    private final JPanel pang;

    public humev() {
        super(nome);

        pang = new JPanel();
        //pang.setLayout(new FlowLayout()); // use appropriate layout .for example flowlayout.since flowlayout is default layout for jpanel you can avoid it.but don't use null
        gioca = new JButton("Gioca!");
        gioca.addActionListener(this);
        lab = new JLabel("lable");

        pang.add(gioca);
        pang.add(lab);
        add(pang); // add pang panel to frame
        Dimension dim_finestra = new Dimension(larghezza, altezza);

        setPreferredSize(dim_finestra);
        setMaximumSize(dim_finestra);
        //setResizable(false);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setVisible(true); 
        pack();

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        humev humev = new humev();
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        if (e.getSource() == gioca) {
            lab.setText("Gioco avviato con successo!");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You cannot add a `label`into a `label` :-

```
lab.add(lab);
```

Aldo you cannot add a `button` on a `button` :-

```
gioca.add(gioca);
```

Try adding them to the `JPanel` or `ContentPane` instead like 
:-

```
pang.add(gioca);
pang.add(lab);
getContentPane().add(pang);
```

**EDIT:-**

For Showing the `JFrame` you need to do first add your `JPanel` to `JFrame` then set the visibility of `JFrame` to `true` something like :-

```
finestra.add(pang); // add panel to frame
finestra.setVisible(true); // show frame visibility to true
```

Also don't set the layout to `null` :-

```
pang.setLayout(null);
```

Else you will need to set the bounds yourself. So just comment this line.

Comment: Thank you very much, the error is no longer displayed but the GUI does not appear. perhaps because the panel is null

Comment: @FrankSoll no its actually beacuuse you are not setting the `visibility` to `true`

Comment: e.g? Where do I enter the code? make an example please. Sorry, I'm a beginner

Comment: you have to set a layout to pang panel first.don't use null .do you want to create 2 frames ? if not remove frame creating code from main method

Comment: but how do I set the visibility to true for the components?

Comment: @FrankSoll see the answer

Comment: @FrankSoll glad that it helped :)

Answer (score 1):

**IllegalArgumentException** is an Unchecked Exception.

It rises explicitly by API Developer or Programmer to indicate that a method has invoked with illegal argument.

example:

```
Thread t = new Thread();
t.setPriority(15);
```

output:

```
RuntimeException: IllegalArgumentExcepion
```

The valid range of Thread priority is 1 to 10, if we are trying to set the priority with any other value, then we will get IllegalArgumentException.

Answer (score -1):

You should add your mysql connector jar file in the lib folder. That's it